# How to plot a ROC curve from TPR and FPR

Tags: r, roc

I have a case where I only get TP, FP, FN and TN for every single data point (one example). In total, I have 24 examples (data points) with these 4 measures. I use 2 different methods and compute TP, FP, FN and TN for each example (data point). Now, I want to compare the performance of these 2 different methods by plotting a ROC curve. I have calculated TPR (y-axis) and FPR (x-axis) and plot them using ggplot2 (see image [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7ixpxzzakrupw2/ROC.png?dl=0)) but I don't know how can I fit the curves on these data points so that they look like classical/traditional ROC curve plots. SO that I can also compute the auROC curve.

Can somebody guide me how to do it? Thank you.

plot using ggplot:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=FPR, y=TPR)) + geom_point(aes(shape=Class, colour = Class), size=1.5) + scale_shape(solid = FALSE) + theme_update(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5)) + xlim(0,1) + xlab("False Positive Rate (FPR)") + ylab("True Positive Rate (TPR)")
```

Here is the dput of my data:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Class = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Epi", 
"GE"), class = "factor"), TP = c(94L, 127L, 58L, 76L, 5L, 6L, 
34L, 47L, 14L, 20L, 113L, 136L, 32L, 36L, 78L, 102L, 51L, 58L, 
49L, 50L, 111L, 120L, 174L, 184L, 151L, 172L, 189L, 226L, 36L, 
40L, 252L, 271L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 42L, 41L, 82L, 0L, 15L, 45L, 53L, 
11L, 16L, 24L, 35L, 3L, 10L, 28L, 34L), FP = c(46L, 389L, 3L, 
254L, 3L, 7L, 13L, 57L, 7L, 88L, 55L, 220L, 21L, 87L, 23L, 245L, 
11L, 190L, 20L, 77L, 45L, 168L, 86L, 391L, 34L, 238L, 88L, 367L, 
56L, 193L, 119L, 455L, 3L, 27L, 5L, 30L, 67L, 247L, 0L, 30L, 
4L, 65L, 7L, 77L, 55L, 176L, 5L, 33L, 15L, 66L), FN = c(33L, 
0L, 18L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 23L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 24L, 0L, 
7L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 21L, 0L, 37L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 19L, 
0L, 5L, 3L, 35L, 0L, 41L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 14L, 3L, 
7L, 0L, 6L, 0L), TN = c(488L, 179L, 373L, 125L, 10L, 6L, 75L, 
32L, 119L, 38L, 247L, 83L, 97L, 37L, 400L, 179L, 295L, 132L, 
107L, 51L, 200L, 109L, 441L, 140L, 331L, 157L, 419L, 177L, 180L, 
45L, 567L, 237L, 35L, 11L, 88L, 91L, 222L, 90L, 0L, 29L, 116L, 
56L, 105L, 36L, 217L, 99L, 55L, 28L, 82L, 32L), TPR = c(0.74, 
1, 0.76, 1, 0.83, 1, 0.72, 1, 0.7, 1, 0.83, 1, 0.89, 1, 0.76, 
1, 0.88, 1, 0.98, 1, 0.92, 1, 0.95, 1, 0.88, 1, 0.84, 1, 0.9, 
1, 0.93, 1, 0.29, 0.57, 0.17, 1, 0.5, 1, 0, 1, 0.85, 1, 0.65, 
0.94, 0.63, 0.92, 0.3, 1, 0.82, 1), FPR = c(0.09, 0.68, 0.01, 
0.67, 0.23, 0.54, 0.15, 0.64, 0.06, 0.7, 0.18, 0.73, 0.18, 0.7, 
0.05, 0.58, 0.04, 0.59, 0.16, 0.6, 0.18, 0.61, 0.16, 0.74, 0.09, 
0.6, 0.17, 0.67, 0.24, 0.81, 0.17, 0.66, 0.08, 0.71, 0.05, 0.25, 
0.23, 0.73, NA, 0.51, 0.03, 0.54, 0.06, 0.68, 0.2, 0.64, 0.08, 
0.54, 0.15, 0.67)), .Names = c("Class", "TP", "FP", "FN", "TN", 
"TPR", "FPR"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

**EDIT:**

This is how the header of data looks like:

```
> head(data)
  Class  TP  FP FN  TN  TPR  FPR
1   Epi  94  46 33 488 0.74 0.09
2    GE 127 389  0 179 1.00 0.68
3   Epi  58   3 18 373 0.76 0.01
4    GE  76 254  0 125 1.00 0.67
5   Epi   5   3  1  10 0.83 0.23
6    GE   6   7  0   6 1.00 0.54
```

I will explain the first 2 rows, the same explantation applies to the rest of them. I used 2 different methods (named `Epi` and `GE`) to calculate number of TP, FP, FN and TN in my predictions about 1 example ( represented in plot by 1 data point). Then I calculate `TPR` and `FPR` from them. Similarly, the same 2 methods I applied on rest of the 23 examples and this entire dataframe gives me the value of TP, FP, FN and TN for each method in every example (24 datapoints - 1 data point representing one example and its TPR/FPR rate calculated by one method i.e. either GE or Epi).

Comment: Something's gone wrong in your calculation of `TPR` and `FPR`. You should only have a single `TPR` at each `FPR`, but you have multiple `TPR`values for a single `FPR`. You should edit your question describing how you calculated these values, and asking where things went wrong.

Comment: @chi-pak for every data point I calculate `TPR` by `TP/(TP+FN)` and `FPR` by `FP/(FP+TN)`. I don't understand why you said that I have multiple `TPR` for a single `FPR`. For every data point I have one `TP, FP, FN and TN` (each) and then I calculate `TPR` and `FPR` for that data point.

Comment: For GE you have a (FPR, TPR) point at (0.25, 1) and then one at (0.7, 0.55) or so. This makes no sense at all: as you increase the TPR, FPR *must* increase or at least stay constant. Clearly you made an error somewhere, so seconding ChiPak please edit your question describing how you calculated these values, and asking where things went wrong.

Comment: @Calimo I have edited my question, kindly see if it makes sense now. I think the problem is that you think the FPR and TPR are for one example, while they are not, every line of this dataframe is independent, the measures (TP, FP, FN and TN) are computed independently for 24 examples and they don't have any relation with any other row in the dataframe.